# "avahi-browse --all" shows less than a specific service?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, avahi, mdns

```
$ avahi-browse --terminate --all
$ avahi-browse --terminate _ipp._tcp
+ enp2s0 IPv4 Canon iR C1538i              Internet Printer     local
+ enp2s0 IPv4 Canon iR1643i II             Internet Printer     local
$
```

What is the reason that `--all` shows nothing, while `_ipp._tcp` *does* have results? How to fix this? (Or is that "normal"?)